# Websites loading slowly or not at all giving DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error

Tags: windows-8, internet

I am having problems with my internet. Some sites load fine (reddit, imgur, armor games), others don't load properly (speedtest.net either fails to configure properly or is all text with a white background), or fails to load at all, giving the error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN (youtube, twitter, any google search and superuser give this). This happens in both chrome and internet explorer and the operating system I'm using is windows 8.

Since this site is one of the ones that doesn't load I am writing this on a different computer (windows 7), but on the same wireless connection and I do not have any of the problems I have listed on this computer. I have done a scan with Malwarebytes, Spybot and Avast which have all turned up nothing. I have also tried entering "netsh winsock reset catalog" into an administrator command prompt window and restarting which did not help. Given that I can load some websites, Killer Network Manager claims that I have over 100mb/s up and down and I can access all sites normally on another computer on the same network, I think that it must be a problem with the computer itself.

Upon measuring my internet speed using the network manager, all pages load properly and at an appropriate speed, but after hitting apply settings the problems occur again. Something else of note is that loading super user while measuring speed works fine, but sometimes after it loads with a banner at the top saying "requires external javascript from another domain which is blocked or failed to load". I am very confused and hope that someone can help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried Firefox I have a possible suspect but I need you to try Firefox before I explain.

Comment: I used the network manager workaround thing to download Firefox and it has the exact same problems as Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Comment: I have no idea what your talking about when you say you used a network manager workaround.

Comment: As I said in the original post, if I use Killer Network Manager to measure my internet speed and leave that window open, everything works fine.

Comment: You don't really say you have to do that.  If you said it, its not stated clearly, hence my confusion.  What if you remove the software.  Does it still work?

Comment: Having removed the manager previously, I know that removing it makes the computer unable to connect to any wireless network at all. If I just close the window or hit the apply settings button that appears after it is finished testing the speed then the problems occur again.

Comment: I assume your using the current version of this software.  This really sounds like either a problem caused by your networking hardware or a driver problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Command Prompt and type: `ipconfig /flushdns`
2. If this doesn't help, install a local DNS proxy, e.g. an open source [Acrylic](http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome)
3. Start the Acrylic service and change your connection's DNS server to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: What if this helps but only **temporarily**? After a while all is broken again.